# Casting pointer to reuse a buffer

Tags: c++, casting, struct, alignment, packet

there:
    I have declaration like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    quint8  mark1;
    quint16 content1;
    quint16 content2;
    quint8  mark2;
}FrameHead;
```

and in function,I defined a buffer,and valued it:

```
quint8 buf[40];
FrameHead *frame  = (FrameHead *)buf;
frame->mark1 = 0x68;
frame->content1 = 0x3A;
frame->content1 = 0x3A;
frame->mark2 = 0x68;
```

So as I thought, the first 6 bytes of *buf* should be "68 3A 00 3A 00 68".But the fact is, the first 8 bytes of *buf* were "68 90 3A 00 3A 00 68 80".And I used:

```
qDebug() << (quint8 *)(++frame) - buf// output "8" but should be "6"
```

seemingly the numbers "0x68" were not stored as *quint8* type but *quint16* type to keep consistency with other *quint16* types.Anyone has encounted the same problems and has any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to alignment. The 16-bit types are aligned on 16-bit adresses. Since your first member only uses 8 bit, 1 byte padding is inserted.

If you reorder your struct to

```
typedef struct
{
    quint8  mark1;
    quint8  mark2;
    quint16 content1;
    quint16 content2;
}FrameHead;
```

it will only use 6 bytes, as no padding is required to align `content1`.

See [Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing) for a more detailed explanation.

**Edit after comment:**

So either you use `#pragma pack(1)` (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (not sure what you mean by

> to set alignment in Qt like "#Pragma" in VC"

) or you simply use an array:

```
typedef quint[6] FrameHead;

....

FrameHead fh1 = {0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x68};
// or 
FrameHead fh2;
memset( fh2, 0, sizeof(FrameHead));
fh2[0] = 0x68;
fh2[5] = 0x68;
```

Comment: thanks johannes S.but I need to format the "buf". The begining byte and end byte of the packet should be "0x68", thats why I insert the "contents1","contents2" into the middle of a struct.Now you taught me the reason causing this problem should be alignment, Is there any way to set alignment in Qt like "#Pragma" in VC.

Comment: @wolfguolei, #pragma pack(1)

Comment: @wolfguolei, also use #pragma pack(push) and #pragma pack(pop) to save and restore the default alignment settings.